# Using the comparison test on $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{(2n)^{1/2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove that the series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{(2n)^{1/2}}$ diverges. Notice that this series is the even terms of the $p$-series with $p=1/2$. I was trying to use the comparison test with the harmonic series to prove that this series diverges. As $\frac{1}{(2n)^{1/2}}>\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 2$. However, doesn't the comparison test state that this need to be true $\forall n$? Or is it valid as long as $\frac{1}{(2n)^{1/2}}>\frac{1}{n}$ when $n\geq N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$? Can I show this using $\delta-\varepsilon$ definitions?

Comment: Convergence always depends on the tail of the series, the first finitely many terms do not matter. Just note that $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2n)^{1/2} }}}  = \frac{1}{{2^{1/2} }} + \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2n)^{1/2} }}}  > \frac{1}{{2^{1/2} }} + \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}} .
$$ I am sure you see that this implies the divergence.

Comment: Convergence  is independent of the first few terms of a series. You can ignore the first few terms in **any test** for convergence.

Comment: You can always pull out a finite number of terms of series, sum them (which will give you a finite result) and then focus your analysis on the infinite tail that remains. So indeed you can assume that $\frac{1}{(2n)^{1/2}} > \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n > N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the comparison test, all that you need is that the inequality holds when $n$ is large enough.

Anyway, you have $\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}\geqslant\frac1{2n}$ for *every* natural number $n$. So, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n}$ diverges, then so does your series.

Answer (score 1):

For an "$\varepsilon -\delta$" proof:

Denote the partial sums by $S_k$. Note that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \frac{1}{n}> \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} \ dx =\log(n+1) - \log(n) $$
So $$S_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} >\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \log(k+1) $$
For any positive number $M$, take an integer $N > e^{\sqrt{2}M}$, then for all $k > N$,
$$S_k > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \sqrt{2}M =M $$
That is, $S_k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$.